# Could not lock /var/lib/apt/lists/

Tags: linux, locking

get update" but i have an problem :

```
Could not lock / var / lib / apt / lists /

pc:/home/hb-17# apt-get update 
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
E: Impossible d'obtenir le verrou /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Ressource temporairement non disponible)
E: Impossible de verrouiller le répertoire /var/lib/apt/lists/
pc:/home/hb-17#
```

thanks for your help;

Answer (score 2):

If there is no apt-get process running, you can safely delete the lock.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of **Error : Unable to lock directory** could occur when there is a software update happening in parallel. Not more than one sudo code can call the root directory at the same time.[with respect to Linux/Ubuntu on a VM]

Below code could be used to check if any other application is running that hinders the other commands on terminal:

```
ps aux | grep '[a]pt'
```

It helps to retrieve the full path of the running application. If there is no parallel application run it returns null.